# pd.rename key KeyError: 'New_Name'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rename

**Edit 12/07/19:** The problem was not in fact with pd.rename fuction but the fact that I did not return from the function the pandas dataframe and as a result the column change did not exist when printing. i.e.

```
def change_column_names(as_pandas, old_name, new_name):
    as_pandas.rename(columns={old_name: new_name}, inplace=)
    return as_pandas <- This was missing*
```

- Please see the user comment below to uptick them for finding this error for me.

Alternatively, you can continue reading.

The data can be downloaded from [this link](http://storage.ning.com/topology/rest/1.0/file/get/2808323526?profile=original), yet I have added a sample dataset.  The formatting of the file is not a typical CSV file and I believe this may have been an assessment piece and is related to [Hidden Decision Tree](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/state-of-the-art-machine-learning-automation-with-hdt) article.  I have given the portion of the code as it solves the issues surrounding the format of the text file as mentioned above and allows the user to rename the column.

The problem occured when I tried to assign create a re-naming function:

```
def change_column_names(as_pandas, old_name, new_name):
    as_pandas.rename(columns={old_name: new_name}, inplace=)
```

However, it seem to work when I set the variable names inside rename function.

```
def change_column_names(as_pandas):
    as_pandas.rename(columns={'Unique Pageviews': 'Page_Views'}, inplace=True)
    return as_pandas
```

Sample Dataset

```
Title   URL Date    Unique Pageviews
oupUrl=tutorials    18-Apr-15   5608
"An Exclusive Interview with Data Expert, John Bottega" http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/an-exclusive-interview-with-data-expert-john-bottega?groupUrl=announcements  10-Jun-14   360
Announcing Composable Analytics http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/announcing-composable-analytics  15-Jun-14   367
Announcing the release of Spark 1.5 http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/announcing-the-release-of-spark-1-5  12-Sep-15   156
Are Extreme Weather Events More Frequent? The Data Science Answer   http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/are-extreme-weather-events-more-frequent-the-data-science-answer 5-Oct-15    204
Are you interested in joining the University of California for an empiricalstudy on 'Big Data'? http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/are-you-interested-in-joining-the-university-of-california-for-an    7-Feb-13    204
Are you smart enough to work at Google? http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/are-you-smart-enough-to-work-at-google   11-Oct-15   3625
"As a software engineer, what's the best skill set to have for the next 5-10years?" http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/as-a-software-engineer-what-s-the-best-skill-set-to-have-for-the-    12-Feb-16   2815
A Statistician's View on Big Data and Data Science (Updated)    http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/a-statistician-s-view-on-big-data-and-data-science-updated-1 21-May-14   163
A synthetic variance designed for Hadoop and big data   http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/a-synthetic-variance-designed-for-hadoop-and-big-data?groupUrl=research  26-May-14   575
A Tough Calculus Question   http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/a-tough-calculus-question    10-Feb-16   937
Attribution Modeling: Key Analytical Strategy to Boost Marketing ROI    http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/attribution-modeling-key-concept 24-Oct-15   937
Audience expansion  http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/audience-expansion   6-May-13    223
Automatic use of insights   http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/automatic-use-of-insights    27-Aug-15   122
Average length of dissertations by higher education discipline. http://www.datasciencecentral.com/forum/topics/average-length-of-dissertations-by-higher-education-discipline   4-Jun-15    1303
```

> This is the full code that produces the Key Error:
>       def change_column_names(as_pandas):
>           as_pandas.rename(columns={'Unique Pageviews': 'Page_Views'}, inplace=True)

```
def change_column_names(as_pandas, old_name, new_name):
    as_pandas.rename(columns={old_name: new_name}, inplace=True)


def change_column_names(as_pandas):
    as_pandas.rename(columns={'Unique Pageviews': 'Page_Views'}, 
                               inplace=True)


def open_as_dataframe(file_name_in):
    reader = pd.read_csv(file_name_in, encoding='windows-1251')
    return reader


# Get each column of data including the heading and separate each element 
i.e. Title, URL, Date, Page Views
# and save to string_of_rows with comma separator for storage as a csv 
# file.
def get_columns_of_data(*args):
    # Function that accept variable length arguments
    string_of_rows = str()
    num_cols = len(args)
    try:
        if num_cols > 0:
            for number, element in enumerate(args):
                if number == (num_cols - 1):
                    string_of_rows = string_of_rows + element + '\n'
                else:
                    string_of_rows = string_of_rows + element + ','

    except UnboundLocalError:
        print('Empty file \'or\' No arguments received, cannot be zero')
    return string_of_rows


def open_file(file_name):
    try:
        with open(file_name) as csv_file_in, open('HDT_data5.txt', 'w') as csv_file_out:
            csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file_in,   delimiter='\t')
            for row in csv_read:
                try:
                    row[0] = row[0].replace(',', '')
                    csv_file_out.write(get_columns_of_data(*row))
                except TypeError:
                    continue

        print("The file name '{}' was successfully opened and read".format(file_name))
    except IOError:
        print('File not found \'OR\' Not in current directory\n')



# All acronyms used in variable naming correspond to the function at time 
# of return from function.
# csv_list being a list of the v file contents the remainder i.e. 'st' of 
# csv_list_st = split_title().
def main():
    open_file('HDTdata3.txt')
    multi_sets = open_as_dataframe('HDT_data5.txt')
    # change_column_names(multi_sets)
    change_column_names(multi_set, 'Old_Name', 'New_Name')
    print(multi_sets)


    main()
```

Comment: Are you sure you _aren't_ running `change_column_names` _after_ you've already run `df.rename(...)`?

Comment: Show your full code.  Sounds like your data frame was created improperly.

Comment: At least enough to reproduce your error.  If your code is too large to post simplify it while maintaining the error.  Your data frame is likely the problem and not Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code so it would run.  You were changing the column names but not returning the result.  Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

def set_new_columns(as_pandas):
    titles_list = ['Year > 2014', 'Forum', 'Blog', 'Python', 'R',
                   'Machine_Learning', 'Data_Science', 'Data', 
                   'Analytics']
    for number, word in enumerate(titles_list):
        as_pandas.insert(len(as_pandas.columns), titles_list[number], 0)

def title_length(as_pandas):
    # Insert new column header then count the number of letters in 'Title'
    as_pandas.insert(len(as_pandas.columns), 'Title_Length', 0)
    as_pandas['Title_Length'] = as_pandas['Title'].map(str).apply(len)

# Although it is log, percentage of change is inverse linear comparison of 
#logX1 - logX2
# therefore you could think of it as the percentage change in Page Views 
# map
# function allows for function to be performed on all rows in column 
# 'Page_Views'.
def log_page_view(as_pandas):
    # Insert new column header
    as_pandas.insert(len(as_pandas.columns), 'Log_Page_Views', 0)
    as_pandas['Log_Page_Views'] = as_pandas['Page_Views'].map(lambda x: math.log(1 + float(x)))

def change_to_numeric(as_pandas):
    # Check for missing values then convert the column to numeric.
    as_pandas = as_pandas.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
    as_pandas['Page_Views'] = pd.to_numeric(as_pandas['Page_Views'],
                                        errors='coerce')

def change_column_names(as_pandas):
    as_pandas.rename(columns={'Unique Pageviews': 'Page_Views'}, inplace=True)
    return as_pandas

def open_as_dataframe(file_name_in):
    reader = pd.read_csv(file_name_in, encoding='windows-1251')
    return reader

# Get each column of data including the heading and separate each element 
# i.e. Title, URL, Date, Page Views
# and save to string_of_rows with comma separator for storage as a csv 
# file.
def get_columns_of_data(*args):
    # Function that accept variable length arguments
    string_of_rows = str()
    num_cols = len(args)
    try:
        if num_cols > 0:
            for number, element in enumerate(args):
                if number == (num_cols - 1):
                    string_of_rows = string_of_rows + element + '\n'
                else:
                    string_of_rows = string_of_rows + element + ','

    except UnboundLocalError:
        print('Empty file \'or\' No arguments received, cannot be zero')
    return string_of_rows

def open_file(file_name):
    import csv
    try:
        with open(file_name) as csv_file_in, open('HDT_data5.txt', 'w') as csv_file_out:
            csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file_in,   delimiter='\t')
            for row in csv_read:
                try:
                    row[0] = row[0].replace(',', '')
                    csv_file_out.write(get_columns_of_data(*row))
                except TypeError:
                    continue

        print("The file name '{}' was successfully opened and read".format(file_name))
    except IOError:
        print('File not found \'OR\' Not in current directory\n')

# All acronyms used in variable naming correspond to the function at time 
# of return from function.
# csv_list being a list of the v file contents the remainder i.e. 'st' of 
# csv_list_st = split_title().
def main():
    open_file('HDTdata3.txt')
    multi_sets = open_as_dataframe('HDT_data5.txt')
    multi_sets = change_column_names(multi_sets)
    change_to_numeric(multi_sets)
    log_page_view(multi_sets)
    title_length(multi_sets)
    set_new_columns(multi_sets)
    print(multi_sets)


main()
```

Comment: Thanks, pass by reference, in this case, pass by value, always trips me up. Cheers